# How do you remove a Gdl.DockItem from Gdl.Dock?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

I'm using the libgdl in Python using GObject introspection. Does anybody know how to remove a Gdl.DockItem from a Gdl.Dock? I've tried:

```
dock.remove(dockitem)
```

and

```
dock.master.remove(dockitem)
```

And I've also tried destroying the dockitem and it's child widget. Can't seem to find an example of where this is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. I was looking for the unbind() method. So, if somebody stumbles upon this, it looks a little like this:

```
dockitem.unbind()
widget.destroy() # where widget was originally added to dock item
```